# How to pass dynamic and static 2d arrays as void pointer?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

for a project using Tensorflow's C API I have to pass a void pointer (void*) to a method of Tensorflow. In the examples the void* points to a 2d array, which also worked for me. However now I have array dimensions which do not allow me to use the stack, which is why I have to use a dynamic array or a vector.

I managed to create a dynamic array with the same entries like this:

```
float** normalizedInputs;//
    normalizedInputs = new float* [noCellsPatches];
    for(int i = 0; i < noCellsPatches; ++i)
    {
        normalizedInputs[i] = new float[no_input_sizes];
    }

for(int i=0;i<noCellsPatches;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<no_input_sizes;j++)
        {
            normalizedInputs[i][j]=inVals.at(no_input_sizes*i+j);
            ////
            ////
            //normalizedInputs[i][j]=(inVals.at(no_input_sizes*i+j)-inputMeanValues.at(j))/inputVarValues.at(j);
        }
    }
```

The function call needing the void* looks like this:

```
TF_Tensor* input_value = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT,in_dims_arr,2,normalizedInputs,num_bytes_in,&Deallocator, 0);
```

In argument 4 you see the "normalizedInputs" array. When I run my program now, the calculated results are totally wrong. When I go back to the static array they are right again. What do I have to change?

Greets and thanks in advance!

Edit: I also noted that the `TF_Tensor* input_value` holds totally different values for both cases (for dynamic it has many 0 and nan entries). Is there a way to solve this by using a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`?
Respectively: is there any valid way pass a consecutive dynamic 2d data structure to a function as void*?

Comment: Show how you declare the *static* version. Your dynamic 2D array is not a true 2D array but an array of pointers. Unfortunately, C++ does not allow programmers to *conformantly* use 2D dynamic arrays...

Comment: I do that in the standard way: float normalizedInputs[noCellsPatches][no_input_sizes];     Is there a way to fix this issue...?

Comment: @tre95 assuming `noCellsPatches` or `no_input_sizes` are not constexpr, that isn't C++. It's a gcc extension.

Comment: These are just standard integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In argument 4 you see the "normalizedInputs" array. When I run my program now, the calculated results are totally wrong.

The reason this doesn't work is because you are passing the pointers array as data. In this case you would have to use `normalizedInputs[0]` or the equivalent more explicit expression `&normalizedInputs[0][0]`. However there is another bigger problem with this code.

Since you are using `new` inside a loop you won't have contiguous data which `TF_NewTensor` expects. There are several solutions to this.

---

If you really need a 2d-array you can get away with two allocations. One for the pointers and one for the data. Then set the pointers into the data array appropriately.

```
float **normalizedInputs = new float* [noCellsPatches]; // allocate pointers
normalizedInputs[0] = new float [noCellsPatches*no_input_sizes]; // allocate data

// set pointers
for (int i = 1; i < noCellsPatches; ++i) {
  normalizedInputs[i] = &normalizedInputs[i-1][no_input_sizes];
}
```

Then you can use `normalizedInputs[i][j]` as normal in C++ and the `normalizedInputs[0]` or `&normalizedInputs[0][0]` expression for your `TF_NewTensor` call.

---

Here is a mechanically simpler solution, just use a flat 1d array.

```
float * normalizedInputs = new float [noCellsPatches*no_input_sizes];
```

You access the `i,j`-th element by `normalizedInputs[i*no_input_sizes+j]` and you can use it directly in the `TF_NewTensor` call without worrying about any addresses.

---

Comment: Ok your first solution seems to work for me, thanks! Can you provide additional information about how to delete it / free the memory? I thought I had to use: ```for(int i = 0; i < noCellsPatches; ++i)
    {
        delete [] normalizedInputs[i];
    }
    delete [] normalizedInputs;``` but then the compilation is successful and my simulation crashes...

Comment: One delete per new, so do it like this. `delete [] normalizedInputs[0]; delete [] normalizedInputs;` the order matters here so do it with [0] first.

Comment: Hey no problem m8

Answer (score 1):

C++ standard does its best to prevent programmers to use raw arrays, specifically multi-dimensional ones.

From your comment, your statically declared array is declared as:

```
float normalizedInputs[noCellsPatches][no_input_sizes];
```

If `noCellsPatches` and `no_input_sizes` are both compile time constants you have a correct program declaring a true 2D array. If they are not constants, you are declaring a 2D Variable Length Array... which does not exist in C++ standard. Fortunately, gcc allow it as an extension, but not MSVC nor clang.

If you want to declare a dynamic 2D array with non constant rows and columns, and use gcc, you can do that:

```
int (*arr0)[cols] = (int (*) [cols]) new int [rows*cols];
```

(the naive `int (*arr0)[cols] = new int [rows][cols];` was rejected by my gcc 5.4.0)

It is definitely not correct C++ but is accepted by gcc and does what is expected.

---

The trick is that we all know that the size of an array of size n in n times the size of one element. A 2D array of `rows` rows of `columns`columns if then `rows` times the size of one row, which is `columns` when measured in underlying elements (here `int`). So we ask gcc to allocate a 1D array of the size of the 2D array and take enough liberalities with the strict aliasing rule to process it as the 2D array we wanted. As previously said, it violates the strict aliasing rule and use VLA in C++, but gcc accepts it.

Comment: My first question (before trying it out) is: bot noCellsPatches and no_input_sizes are constant member variables of the class I am using. I initialize them with the initialization list of the constructor. The shall be constant. If I use the following: ``` 
float (*normalizedInputs)[no_input_sizes] = new float[noCellsPatches][no_input_sizes];``` 
 I get this error: ```array size in new-expression must be constant``` which I do not understand, as these are constant values? However I will try your solution later this afternoon!

Comment: @tre95: Beware `const` is not `constexpr`. A `const` value initialized in the initialization list of the ctor is generally not a *compile time* constant. *array size in new-expression must be constant* is raised by gcc when the type is a VLA - the reason why I had to use the hacky `new int [rows*cols];`...

Comment: Ok your command runs in my application, although I do not fully understand it! Massive Thanks! However one further question - I guess I have to free the dynamic memory, right? Is it enough to use ```delete [] arr0```?

Comment: Ok I tried your solution, but unfortunately during my time loop after some time I get an error and the program crashes again. Obviously the input tensor for the method now holds the correct values, but the Tensorflow method still calculates the wrong results.... this is getting very confusing...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understand now!